# Tab separated values Go package joho/sqltocsv

Tags: csv, go, delimiter

I am using  Go **joho/sqltocsv** package to convert  SQL rows to CSV file.
Package what i am using: [github.com/joho/sqltocsv](https://github.com/joho/sqltocsv)

All works fine, except that i have not found any solution to change delimiter from ,(default) to /t (tab)

I tried to implement somehow :

```
    writer = csv.NewWriter(w)
    writer.Comma = '\t'
```

but without any success

Firstly i tried to implement it to:

```
rows, _ := db.Query(sqlQuery)
err = sqltocsv.WriteFile(directory+"/"+fileName, rows)
```

And after i moved on to:

```
rows, _ := db.Query(sqlQuery)
csvConverter := sqltocsv.New(rows)
csvConverter.WriteFile(directory + "/" + fileName)
```

But also with that way i did not find any good solution to implement writer.Comma ..

Excepted result would be tab separated values in CSV instead of comma separated values.

Any help would be appreciated :).

Answer (score 0):

writer.Comma = '\t'

did the trick, just pulled the code from his repo and added it to line 97 on sqltocsv.go

Edit:
Guy named Jeffi has already turned this to pull request and found it from his repo.
https://github.com/jeffyi/sqltocsv

so using this instead of johos.

(found it thanks to @dm03514)

Comment: Ahh sh.. Did not see that. That pull request should be aproved :).